# Any way to exclude the last - character if the item is the last in the list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make this not include the last " -" if the item is the last one in the list. I'm not up to par with Python so any help would be appreciated!

```
def GetList(data):
"""Get list of all enabled rewards"""
RewardList = getattr(MySet, "listbase")
for x in range(1, MaxRewards):
    if getattr(MySet, "r{0}enabled".format(x)) and Parent.HasPermission(data.User, getattr(MySet, "r{0}permission".format(x)), getattr(MySet, "r{0}permissioninfo".format(x))):
        RewardList += (getattr(MySet, "r{0}name".format(x)) + " ")
        if getattr(MySet, "listcost"):
            RewardList += ("(" + str(getattr(MySet, "r{0}cost".format(x))) + " name" + ")" + " - ")
return RewardList
```

Comment: Your code has seemingly nothing to do with your question. Please add more details.

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: I'm confused as to how it's not related? The code is printing a list of items and adding a "-" after each one. But it does this even if it's the last item. So please tell me how my question isn't related to the code? It's all right there?

Comment: You have a bunch of code that doesn't execute due to unknown variables.  Make a [mcve] and explain what you are trying to do, expected input and output vs. actual.

Comment: The code doesn't need to execute to be able to answer my question. I've seen similar questions be answered and people actually HELP. So I'm not sure why I'm getting flack here. All examples I've found don't seem to match or work with the code I showed. So any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The normal technique for this sort of thing is to have the separator as a variable and change it’s value to an empty string for the last element via an `if` test or similar in the loop body before the print call.

For example,

```
def GetList(data):
    """Get list of all enabled rewards"""
    RewardList = getattr(MySet, "listbase")
    separator = ' - '
    for x in range(1, MaxRewards):
        if x == MaxRewards - 1:
            separator = ''
        if getattr(MySet, "r{0}enabled".format(x)) and Parent.HasPermission(data.User, getattr(MySet, "r{0}permission".format(x)), getattr(MySet, "r{0}permissioninfo".format(x))):
            RewardList += (getattr(MySet, "r{0}name".format(x)) + " ")
            if getattr(MySet, "listcost"):
                RewardList += ("(" + str(getattr(MySet, "r{0}cost".format(x))) + " name" + ")" + separator)
    return RewardList
```

Comment: That still seems to be adding the "-" to the last item. Thanks for the help thus far. I normally stick to JS, CSS, PHP, HTML.

Comment: @vem0m collect the strings in a list and use `'-'.join(lst)`.

Comment: I've been trying variations of doing that but all examples found don't seem to match the code I'm working with.